# Java EE 6 backward compatible to Java EE 5?

Tags: netbeans, jakarta-ee, dependencies, glassfish

We have a Java EE 5 project developed using Netbeans 6.7.1 with Glassfish v2.1. Trying to open this project with Netbeans 6.9.1 with Glassfish v3.1 there are many errors concerning missing types.

Is Java EE 6 backward compatible with Java EE 5?

The missing libraries generally revolve around:

```
javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
org.jvnet.staxex.StreamingDataHandler;
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder;
```

Any ideas?

**[Update]**

It seems that not all of the required libraries are being added to the classpath for a Glassfish 3.1 project automatically. The main missing jar is `jaxrpc-api-osgi.jar` under *glasshfish3/glassfish/modules/*. If I add this jar manually all the problems go away. Why would this be the case? Why isn't the jar added automatically as is done using NetBeans 6.7.1 with Glassfish 2.1?

**[Update]**

I managed to hunt down `org.jvnet.staxex.StreamingDataHandler; and com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder;` via:

- com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.StreamingDataHandler;
- com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder;

Looks like some package changing went on. Still, this doesn't fix my problem with `javax.xml.rpc.Stub; and javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;` not being added to my classpath correctly. I don't feel it's right to add the jar manually.

Wulfgarpro

Comment: JDK 1.6 has complete [web services support](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/webservices.jsp), which means many `javax.xml` packages and SOAP support is included in the JDK itself. I guess this is what is causing a problem.

Comment: @CMR - so you're saying there are conflicts?

Comment: I personally have faced problems when I ported my JDK5 project which had XML libraries included to JDK6.

Comment: @CMR - recommendations on how to rectify?

Comment: I do not have an elegant solution. I would start by removing all xml libraries. If the compilation still fails, try adding the XML libraries to the end of classpath, till you identify the problem... Sorry, I really have not spent enough time researching the reasons for the problem.

Comment: Also, please post how you solved your problem. I am very interested to know

Comment: @CMR - still working on it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling all JDK, JRE, and NetBeans. Reinstalling, the issue was rectified.

WulfgarPro

Answer (score 2):

*Nothing* is ever completely backwards compatible, but having those classes not showing up at *all* is suspicious.  At least the first two are definitely in Java EE/Java 6.  If there were incompatibilities I'd expect something like parameter mismatches or methods not found.

First place I'd look is at the Netbeans project setup -- I'd bet a small amount of money that your classpath.search path doesn't include something you need.

Comment: the project.properties notes, `j2ee.platform=1.5`. I usually use Eclipse; i'm not sure where the classpath.search path is located?

Comment: @Wulfgar, I don't use either one regularly, being a True Believer in the Cult of EMACS.  But this article http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html describes the projects in some detail, including how to import an Eclipse project.

Comment: ... more: here's the classpath in the project properties browser: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath

Answer (score 0):

`javax.xml.rpc` is present in both EE 5 and 6. So this can't be about API version incompatibility. There must be a problem with the way your Netbeans project is set up.

Comment: thanks for the insight. I will note that, in NetBeans, if I expand the Glassfish node under Libraries, there is no mention of `javaee.jar`. If I manually add this library to the project, all the problems go away. If I use Glassfish 2.1 rather than 3.1 all the issues go away. So my question is; why is it that if I install a fresh copy of NetBeans 6.9.1 the proper jar files are missing?

Comment: Just trying this now on my home machine with a fresh Web Project in NetBeans.. `javax.xml.rpc` exists.. this leads me to believe the problem does lie within the way the project is set up.

Comment: @Wulfgar: You might want to reframe the question based on this new information. The question as is currently been formulated makes little sense (too localized) and the answer is simply "yes".

Comment: @BalusC - I made some extended comments.